# Cant get a query running

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1242

I have to find a result based on the following tables

Students
StudentPapersSelection as sps
StudentGroupManagegemt as sgm
Internal Data as iars

From student I need students rollno and name where iars's paperid = sps's paperid and iars groupid= sgm group id and students id should be based on the previous two things.

The query I am running is:

```
select students.rollno, students.name 
from students,sps,iars,sgm 
where iars.id=1
and students.studentid=(select studentid 
                        from sps where sps.paperid=iars.paperid
                        and iars.id=1)
and students.studentid=(select studentid 
                        from sgm 
                        where sgm.groupid=iars.groupid 
                        and iars.id=1) 
and students.course=iars.courseid  
and students.semester=iars.semester
```

It says query returning more than 1 rows. I hate this problem.

Comment: How about describing the schema for your tables in the question so we get a better idea of how your data is structured?

Comment: All the tables associated with it ?

Comment: yes because you have a number of subqueries, and as such, it is difficult to see which of them actually returns more than one row. Alternatively, you can try running your subqueries independently, and see if any of them return more than one row.

Comment: Seems one of your subqueries have more the one result, try to fix this. In worst case try `select studentid from sps where sps.paperid=iars.paperid and
iars.id=1 Limit 1`

Comment: I have tried running them separately and they are running fine. Wait let me put up it for you.

Comment: i want more than one result @AndreasRohde

Comment: Then use a join or `and students.studentid in ( ....`. The second one is not the preffered one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try I guess:

```
select  students.rollno,
        students.name
from    iars, students join sps on students.studentid = sps.studentid
        join sgm on students.studentid = sgm.studentid
where   iars.id = 1 
and     sps.paperid=iars.paperid
and     sgm.groupid=iars.groupid
and     students.course = iars.courseid
and     students.semester = iars.semester
```

Assuming tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `studentid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rollno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `course` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `semester` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`studentid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=66820 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `sps` (
  `studentid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `paperid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`studentid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=66820 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `sgm` (
  `studentid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `groupid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`studentid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=66820 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `iars` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `paperid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `groupid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `courseid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `semester` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=66820 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And data like this:

```
insert into students values (1,1,'a',1,1);
insert into students values (2,1,'b',1,1);
insert into iars values(1,1,1,1,1);
insert into sgm values (1,1);
insert into sps values (1,1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Wish it was that simple for me. Seriously, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your comments and from the limited information in your question, it seems what you want to do instead of

`...students.studentid=(select studentid ...`

is to replace both occurances with

`...students.studentid in(select studentid ...`

So your query should be something like:

```
select students.rollno, students.name from students,sps,iars,sgm where iars.id=1
    and students.studentid in (select studentid from sps 
        where sps.paperid=iars.paperid and iars.id=1) 
    and students.studentid in (select studentid from sgm
        where sgm.groupid=iars.groupid and iars.id=1) 
    and students.course=iars.courseid 
    and students.semester=iars.semester
```

Comment: What i want is that it should students from the student table where the studentid should be in the group A and studying paper 2 . and the paperno and the groupno will depend on the iars table which will match them from sps and sgm table

Comment: i have. its not doing anything. it stops on "Loading"